# GeoServer not responding to OpenLayers 6 GetFeature request, after enabling CORS filter in the file located at webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, cors

[instructional URL/link of enabling CORS for GeoServer](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/container.html#enable-cors)

File location/Directory

[image: File location]

As given on the website, I uncommented my the filter in web.xml file to enable CORS,

[image: uncommented block 1]

[image: uncommented block 2]

but now I can not access the GeoServer service.

[image: after enabling CORS]

and even after returning the web.xml file to original format. I am not able to access the WMS layers, because instead of opening the layer in new tab, it is downloading it as WMS file.

[image: WMS file downloading instead of opening the layer]

so have to remove and reinstall the whole GeoServer.

How do I rectify this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had the same issue. Assuming you have Tomcat underneath, try this:

1. Ignore the filters which were already in the file but commented. Comment them back.
2. Add this instead:

   ```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
          <init-param>
             <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
             <param-value>*</param-value>
          </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
   ```

EDIT: This goes before the first `<filter-mapping>` tag

Answer (score 3):

The instructions on the website work for the Jetty container used in the "bin" distribution. However, you deployed on Tomcat, which would require a  different set of declarations. See other answers here, specifically targetting Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

As [Romah](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/12995/romah) points out you have not uncommented the filter correctly - an XML comment is `<!-- ..... -->` so you need to remove the entire `<!--` and `-->` in order for the `web.xml` file to be valid.